# insert break point after certain number of characters

Tags: php, substr

How do I insert break point after certain number of break points

Like my string is ' Celebrating Founder’s Day ' and I call function to insert break point after 6 characters means it should return me  ' Celebrating 
 Founder’s Day ' it should take the nearest space to insert the break point not at the character length given.

```
    if ( mb_strlen( $str) > $charlength ) {
        $subex = mb_substr( $str, 0, $charlength - 5 );
        $exwords = explode( ' ', $subex );
        $excut = - ( mb_strlen( $exwords[ count( $exwords ) - 1 ] ) );
        if ( $excut < 0 ) {
            echo mb_substr( $subex, 0, $excut );
        } else {
            echo $subex;
        }
    } else {
        echo $str;
    }
```

I did not understand how to change this to insert the break point after certain characters

This code extracts the string of given character length

I did not understand this code to modify to insert break point after certain number of character length..

Comment: in your example the break point is after 12 characters, not 6?

Comment: Seems like an homework to me..

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried but basic logic:

```
function breakPoint($string, $offset) {
    $place  = strpos($string, ' ', $offset);
    if($place !== false) {
        return substr($string, 0, $place)."\n".substr($string, $place+1);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

You should look for [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.